# What awaits the Task returned by an IHandleWithTask event handler

Tags: caliburn.micro

I've searched all over the CM source both version 1.5.2 and 2.0 and I cannot find anything that awaits the Task returned by an event Subscriber using the public Task IHandleWithTask signature.  If nothing is awaiting the task, what is the point of returning a Task at all.  Why not just use the public void IHandle signature?

```
      John
```

Comment: Might be some help to be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417354/will-caliburn-micro-do-the-right-thing-with-async-method-on-viewmodel, and the links mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is awaited.
The bootsrapper or CaliburnApplication registers a handler to `EventAggregator.HandlerResultProcessing`. The task is not awaited but it is wrapped by a Coroutine and the `Coroutine.Completed` handler writes a log entry.